# How to create configuration to specify Source(DB) and Destinations dynamically in Talend?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, etl, talend

I have to move data from Oracle to PostgreSQL on Amazon cloud. I want to know if there are any ways to take care of configuration related issues.I want to take connection string ,userID, password and other credentials dynamically.How am I supposed to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **tFileInputProperties** component for that. There you can set the type of the configuration file (.properties or .ini) and the path of the configuration file. The output is a key value pair row. Connect it with **tContextLoad**. If the key in the configuration file is the same as the context variable name, then it will set the value.
Here is the overview of the .properties file structure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties

And here is the .ini file structure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the jobs `Context` variables directly and pass them when starting the job.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an enterprise version of Talend, with Talend Administration Center, you can input the context variables also in the task definition, in Job Conductor page. It is more convenient than putting properties file on the VM disc where the job server is running.

Small tip = if you decide to use properties file, please note that oracle password should be in double quotes, if it includes special characters. I do not know about PostgreSQL but MySQL password should NOT be with double quotes.